# Referencing an Unbound DataGridView Without Specifically Naming It?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am using 3 unbound DataGridView controls to display certain information. To load the information into those DGVs, I am pulling the information from an encrypted file, decrypting it, parsing the information, then trying to fill the DGVs with that information.  The loading from the file is called by the menu item click.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub miCLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles miCLoad.Click
    Dim FilePath As String = "C:\FList\CList.clt"
    Dim LoadFile As New SaveandLoad.SaveAndLoad
    Dim FileRead As New Simple3Des("MyPassword")
    Dim FileString As String = FileRead.ReadFile(FilePath)


    With LoadFile
        .WhichList = dgCourses
        .FilePath = FilePath
        .DecryptedString = FileRead.DecryptData(FileString)
        .dgList = dgCourses
    End With

    Call LoadFile.LoadFile()
End Sub

Public Class SaveandLoad
Public Property WhichList As New DataGridView
Public Property FilePath As String
Public Property DecryptedString As String
Public Property EncryptedString As String
Public Property dgList As Control

Public Sub LoadFile()

    Dim dgRow As DataGridViewRow
    Dim dgCell As DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    Dim Lines() As String = DecryptedString.Split(vbLf)
    Dim LinesList As List(Of String) = Lines.ToList
    LinesList.RemoveAt(Lines.Length - 1)

    For Each Line As String In LinesList
        Dim Fields() As String = Line.Split(",")
        dgRow = New DataGridViewRow

        For x = 0 To (WhichList.Columns.Count - 1) Step 1
            dgCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
            dgCell.Value = Fields(x).ToString
            dgRow.Cells.Add(dgCell)
        Next
        WhichList.Rows.Add(dgRow)
    Next

    Select Case WhichList.Name
        Case "dgCourses"
            frmFacultyList.dgCourses = WhichList
            frmFacultyList.dgCourses.Refresh()
            WhichList.Dispose()
        Case "dgFList"
            frmFacultyList.dgFList = WhichList
            frmFacultyList.dgFList.Refresh()
            WhichList.Dispose()
        Case "dgSList"
            frmFacultyList.dgSList = WhichList
            frmFacultyList.dgSList.Refresh()
            WhichList.Dispose()
    End Select

    MsgBox("List Successfully Loaded", vbOKOnly, "Load")

End Sub
```

I want to be able to reference (or fill) a DGV without using 'select case' or 'if-then' statements.  This will be too inefficient once I start adding the many other DGVs, that will be added in the future. Therefore, the title is the main question.  I am using VS Express 2010.

Comment: It seems I have answered my own question through answering another person's question.  I just simply created an instance of the main form's control collection and was able to run a for each from there.  If anyone can come up with a code example, I'll give you the credit.  If not, I'll answer my own question tomorrow (Have to wait 8 hours before I can).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me in VB.NET:

```
Dim FormControls As New frmFacultyList.ControlCollection(frmFacultyList)

        For Each DGV As DataGridView In FormControls
            If WhichList.Name = DGV.Name Then
                DGV = WhichList
                DGV.Refresh()
            End If
        Next
```

Make an instance of the control collection then search specifically for DGVs using For Each.  Simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VB too much, however, I'll post my solution in C# (may be helpfull in some way....)

```cs
DataGridView myDGV;
foreach (var item in this.Controls)
{
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(DataGridView))
    {
        if (((DataGridView)item).Name == WhichList.Name)
        {
            //Cannot assing to 'item' here,  because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'
            //However you can save the variable for later use.
            myDGV = (DataGridView)item;
        }
    }
}
myDGV = WhichList;




// different approach
DataGridView myDGV = (DataGridView)this.Controls.Find(WhichList.Name, false).First();
myDGV = WhichList;
```

Comment: Your different approach was very close.  Same logic, though: 'code' Dim FormControls As New frmFacultyList.ControlCollection(frmFacultyList)

            For Each DGV As DataGridView In FormControls
                If WhichList.Name = DGV.Name Then
                    DGV = WhichList
                    DGV.Refresh()
                End If
            Next 'code'